# How to add uniswap v3 liquidity from a code smart contract?

Tags: uniswap, polygon

https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88#code

```
address constant NonfungiblePositionManager = 0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88;
```

Create my token.

```
ERC20 token = new Token("MY token", "MYTKN");
```

Approve token.

```
token.approve(NonfungiblePositionManager, 1_000_000 * 10**18);
```

Uniswap V2

```
uniswap = IUniswap(NonfungiblePositionManager);
uniswap.addLiquidityETH{ value: msg.value }(
    token,
    amountTokenDesired,
    amountTokenMin,
    amountETHMin,
    msg.sender,
    deadline
);
```

How to create liquidity pair (`MATIC`-`MYTKN`) using Uniswap V3?
How to add liquidity using Uniswap V3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example of adding liquidity on a Uniswap V3 pool: https://solidity-by-example.org/defi/uniswap-v3-liquidity/